# php foreach issue

Tags: php, dom

I'm using simple_html_dom_helper so do some screen scraping and am encountering some errors.

The second foreach runs 4 times (since `sizeof($pages) == 4`), while it should only run once. I got this code from an example script where `table.result-liste` occurs several times on the page. In my case it only occurs once, so imho there is no need for a foreach. **The `print_r($data)` prints out the same thing 4 times** and there's no need for that.

Further down I'm trying to do the same without the foreach but it just prints out `no`, so there seems to a different response and am not sure why.

```
foreach( $pages as $page )
        {
            $p = $this->create_url($codes[0], $price, $page); //pass page number along          
            $p_html = file_get_html($p);

            $row = $p_html->find("table[class=result-liste] tr");

            //RUNS OK BUT NO NEED TO DO IT FOUR TIMES.
            //CLASS RESULT-LISTE ONLY OCCURS ONCE ANYWAY
            foreach( $p_html->find("table[class=result-liste] tr") as $row)
            {
                //grab only rows where there is a link 
                if( $row->find('td a') )
                {
                    $d_price = $this->get_price($row->first_child());
                    $d_propid = $this->get_prop_id($row->outertext);

                    $data = array(
                        "price"     => $d_price,
                        "prop_id"   => $d_propid
                    );

                    print_r($data);
                }                                               
            }

            //MY ATTEMPT TO AVOID THE SECOND FOREACH DOES NOT WORK ...
            $row = $p_html->find("table[class=result-liste] tr");
            if( is_object($row) && $row->find('td a')) print "yes ";
            else print "no ";           
        }
```

Comment: As far as I understand, the second foreach is finding rows in the indicated table. How many rows does the table have?

Comment: The very first row never has a link, but the subsequent ones all do.

Comment: @stef that's your problem then.  In your attempt, you are only retrieving the first row, which never has a link.  The `$row->find('td a')` never succeeds because the links are in the subsequent rows you need the `foreach` to get to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the `table[class=result-liste]` only occurs once on your page, this find statement is looking for the `<tr>` elements that are the table's rows.  So unless your table has only one row, you will need this `foreach`.

```
$p_html->find("table[class=result-liste] tr")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code**

```
        foreach( $p_html->find("table[class=result-liste] tr") as $row)
        {
            //grab only rows where there is a link 
            if( $row->find('td a') )
            {
                $d_price = $this->get_price($row->first_child());
                $d_propid = $this->get_prop_id($row->outertext);

                $data = array(
                    "price"     => $d_price,
                    "prop_id"   => $d_propid
                );

                print_r($data);
            }                                               
        }
```

**Replace above code by MY code**

```
        $asRow = $p_html->find("table[class=result-liste] tr");
        $row = $asRow[0];

            //grab only rows where there is a link 
            if( $row->find('td a') )
            {
                $d_price = $this->get_price($row->first_child());
                $d_propid = $this->get_prop_id($row->outertext);

                $data = array(
                    "price"     => $d_price,
                    "prop_id"   => $d_propid
                );

                print_r($data);
            }
```

Try with this.